# How get one phrase from HTML by JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

For example i have HTML-block:

```
<h2><a href="http://google.ru" style="text-decoration: underline;"><img src="http://any_image.jpg"/></a>some_text</h2>
```

And i want to get word "some_text". If i use code like this:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("h2");
```

I will get all code. Help please, i'm newer in JSOUP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String text = doc.select("h2").first().text();
```